# Cant fetch data from firestore using whereIn in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get certain documents from one collection based on the data collected from the other collection. I am getting 4 documents in the guest list but getting 0 elements in joinedGuests.

```
  Future getData()async{
    List<String>guests=[];
    
    final QuerySnapshot result= await 
     firestore.collection('events').document(widget.eventCode).collection('guests').getDocuments();
    
    result.documents.forEach((element)=>guests.add(element.data['user']));
    
    final QuerySnapshot joinedGuests=await firestore.collection('users').where("uid",whereIn: 
     guests).getDocuments();
    
    return joinedGuests.documents;
  }
```

[events collection Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhy9K.png)

[users collection database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCkX6.png)

Comment: Could you show the output of "result" and guests after the for each? as well as any error or result that you get from "joinedGuests"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... at least in example shown on the screenshot `uid` value in `users` collection has space value.

like: `" PLRNk...(etc.)"` in `guest` collection it seems to be like: `"PLRNk...(etc.)"`

Seems to be simple, but it's not the first time I see it... :P

I hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was struggling from 2 days. It worked

Comment: Good to hear... I will appreciate if you accept the answer ;)